# How to use this phrase on an invitation

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is is grammatically correct to say bride to be of Grady Clark or bride to be to Grady Clark? Need it on an invitation for a bridal shower.

Comment: I suggest you go and look at examples on the internet as invitations styles can get very complicated. Bride to be is not something I personally would use on an invitation.

Comment: Nowadays, the man is often included and if he isn't the term bride to be would not: https://www.theknot.com/content/bridal-shower-invitation-wording-ideas

Answer (score 1):

One is a bride, or bride-to-be, **of** a person, not **to** a person.

On the other and, when they tie the knot, they will get married **to** the person.

Answer (score 0):

"Bride" is a woman shortly before or shortly after her wedding. It is up to you what "short" means, but I guess if the "bridal shower" is in the days before the wedding that would be "short".  You can just say "The bride of Grady Clark".

It seems odd not to use the woman's name in this context. You may consider rephasing:

> Please join us honouring (Bride's name) as we celebrate her upcoming wedding to Grady Clark.

Comment: I appreciate that you've made very helpful comments that could help the questioner improve the invitation, but you appear to have missed answering the *actual* question.

Comment: James, I cannot imagine - as a friend of the bride throwing her a shower - using such formal language. It sounds like Windsor Palace speech. Girlfriends of brides are usually less formal and a lot warmer.

Comment: I copied that phrase from an actual bridal shower invitation. This is exactly how these things may be written.

Comment: As I said, it is extremely formal. But I notice it does not contain bride to be in any form, which I agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences make sense—but they have different meanings.

> Bride-to-be **of** Grady Clark.

This simply means that she is the person who will become Grady Clark's bride.

This is also the way you would phrase it on an invitation, since it's the most normal meaning of the situation, and how everybody would view the person.

---

> Bride-to-be **to** Grady Clark.

This means that Grady Clark *considers* her to be his bride-to-be. *To him*, she is his bride-to-be.

It's possible that he hasn't proposed to her yet. But, in his mind, that's how he thinks of her.

An analogy would be peanuts. One person is allergic to them, another finds them delicious.  You could say:

> Peanuts are forbidden **to** A, but they are delicious **to** B.

The peanuts mean something different to each person.